# How to dump routines and triggers using mysqldump with --tab option?

Tags: sql, triggers, mysql

When I was using mysqldump without --tab option I could dump routines (by --routines option) and triggers (by --triggers that enabled by default), but when trying to use --tab to get its benefit of speed I couldn't dump neither routines nor triggers even when specifying the two options (--routines and --triggers) but instead I found the SQL for triggers and stored procedures creation in the terminal I'm using to execute the command.

How can I dump routines and triggers using the --tab option in mysqldump ?

Thanks

Abdel-Mawla

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to split your mysqldump script to first dump the tables using --tab, and then dump the routines through a separate mysqldump call (without --tab).

Answer (score 0):

I see the triggers are saved to the individual table files with `--tab` and `--triggers`.

But for the routines, I can confirm that these are thrown out to stdout.
The same applies for --events
All I could think of is:

```
mysqldump --tab='/path/to/output/dbName' --triggers --routines --events dbName > /path/to/output/dbName/_events.and.routines.sql
```

Because when the routines are thrown to the stdout, the > can put it into a file.

So now in /path/to/output/dbName I will have an extra file called _events.and.routines.sql, containing the routines and events.

I just don't know if mysqlimport will also take in these exported routines automatically.